# Pasting text into emacs on Macintosh

Tags: emacs, terminal, mouse, paste, macos

I'm on a Macintosh and am using "terminal" for my shell.  When I copy text from any window (via mouse drag then right mouse button menu -> copy) and then I paste the text (right mouse button -> paste) into a terminal with emacs running, it doesn't act as a paste.  Instead, it is just like entering or typing in text.  The problem occurs when the text is indented.  Emacs does its auto-indentation on top of that so I get a cascading staircase-like look of text.  I just want it to be a true "paste" so that whatever was copied shows up exactly as it was.  Any ideas on how to change something to get this to work?

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect this to work.  A text terminal doesn't have a "paste".  Terminal.app implements paste by typing in all the characters on the clipboard.  If you want paste to work differently, don't run programs in a text terminal.

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
(defun pt-pbpaste ()
  "Paste data from pasteboard."
  (interactive)
  (shell-command-on-region
   (point)
   (if mark-active (mark) (point))
   "pbpaste" nil t))

(defun pt-pbcopy ()
  "Copy region to pasteboard."
  (interactive)
  (print (mark))
  (when mark-active
    (shell-command-on-region
     (point) (mark) "pbcopy")
    (kill-buffer "*Shell Command Output*")))

(global-set-key [?\C-x ?\C-y] 'pt-pbpaste)
(global-set-key [?\C-x ?\M-w] 'pt-pbcopy)
```

Use `C-x C-y` to paste and `C-x M-w` to copy.

Comment: Does C stand for "Control or Ctrl" key in the keyboard here?

Answer (score 2):

For a quick and dirty solution which doesn't require configuring custom commands, you can run `shell-command` with a prefix argument to insert the results of calling `pbpaste` into the current buffer.

Thus:

```
C-u M-! pbpaste <RET>
```