# Undo external paste when using Terminal.app

Tags: macos, emacs, emacs24

I'm pasting a multiline text into Emacs and it gets inserted atomically. However, to undo it, you have to press <kbd>C-/</kbd> (or <kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>undo</kbd><kbd>⏎</kbd>) repeatedly, undoing one line at a time. Is it normal?

How to undo a paste operation with a single <kbd>C-/</kbd>?

Comment: Do you run emacs in a terminal, or as an X application?

Comment: @choroba, it happens only in a terminal, the GUI version is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running Emacs on Mac OS terminal, this solution might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3963229/114833

Comment: Yeah, `pbcopy` and `pbpaste`! Cool!

Answer (score 3):

When running Emacs in a terminal, the paste really goes to the terminal, not Emacs. Emacs recieves the keys one by one from the terminal.

There are some workarounds, but none is as simple as an Undo: e.g., paste to `*scratch*`, then kill-n-yank from there. Or, before pasting, press <kbd>C-space</kbd>. Then you can undo with just pressing <kbd>C-w</kbd>.

Comment: The `C-space` solution while clever isn't working, but I get what you saying. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I actually have some custom elisp i use which undoes all modifications since the last save point.  if you save frequently (which i do), this gives a nice logical undo-ability.  assuming you saved the buffer before pasting the block, this would remove the entire paste.  (note, it works across multiple save points, meaning you can undo a savepoint at a time going back in undo history).

```
(defun undo-last-modification ()
  "Undo all changes since last save point in the buffer."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((repeat-undo (eq last-command 'undo))
         (cur-undo-list (if repeat-undo pending-undo-list buffer-undo-list))
         (head (car-safe cur-undo-list))
         (tail (cdr-safe cur-undo-list))
         (found-next-mod nil)
         (num-undos 0))

    ;; when in the midst of undoing, the first nil gets chopped off the list,
    ;; so add one if the list doesn't start with nil
    (if head (setq num-undos (1+ num-undos)))

    ;; search for next save point in the undo list
    (while (not found-next-mod)
      (if (not head)
          (setq num-undos (1+ num-undos))
        (if (and (listp head) (eq (car-safe head) t))
            (setq found-next-mod t)))
      (if tail
          (progn
            (setq head (car-safe tail))
            (setq tail (cdr-safe tail)))
        ;; end of list
        (setq found-next-mod t))
      )

    (if (> num-undos 0)
        (undo num-undos))
    )
)
```

Comment: I like the general idea of reverting to a save point. It might be not only a save-to-disk but some abstract register entry. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... I was about to suggest to use a `pre-command-hook` that removes the last `undo-boundary` if the time since last command is very short.  But I see that the undo-boundary is added *after* running `pre-command-hook`, so that's not an option.  You might like to `M-x report-emacs-bug`, asking that such a thing be made possible (or even provided by default).

Answer (score 0):

You can put this `(global-set-key [f5] 'undo);` into your emacs config file, i.e. *.emacs*, then F5 command will help you undo last operation, including paste. Actually, you can set the key whatever you like besides F5.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I'm asking about.